# How to remove outer array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

I wanted to remove outer array of objects. And I have tried to remove the outer array by writing below code.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  EmployeeData=[
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [{
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          } ]}]
    },
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [
          {
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          }]}
      ]
    }
  ]
 ngOnInit(){
   
    this.arr = this.EmployeeData[0];
   console.log(this.arr)
  }
}
```

I am getting below data format as a result. There are two objects inside the array. But I am getting only one object here.

```
{
  "name": [
    {
      "grade": "A",
      "position": "JSE",
      "data": [
        {
          "commission": 271,
          "address": "street1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But my expected output should be

```
   {"name": [{
       "grade": "A",
       "position": "JSE",
       "data": [{
           "commission": 271,
           "address": "street1"
         } ]}]
   },
   {"name": [{
       "grade": "A",
       "position": "JSE",
       "data": [
         {
           "commission": 271,
           "address": "street1"
         }]}
     ]
   }
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this

Comment: `this.EmployeeData` is an array with two objects. So `this.EmployeeData[0]` is the first object. There is no error here?

Comment: You're accessing the first element of array using [0], it cannot return elements when you're accessing a single index. Either you get the second object using `this.EmployeeData[1]`, or change how array is arranged.

Comment: You can not have an object with a duplicated property. Your object would hold `name` two times, which will simply not work. One of them will be overwritten. Besides, by accessing `[0]` or `[1]` of an array, you will get the single element that is stored at said index. It's supposed to return *one* entry only.

Comment: To get the output you want it's just a matter of using `this.EmployeeData` directly instead of accessing a nested entry by index. If you want the array of objects, then you need to reference the array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It is not possible in Javascript for a single thing to be what you want, namely:

```
  {"name": [{
       "grade": "A",
       "position": "JSE",
       "data": [{
           "commission": 271,
           "address": "street1"
         } ]}]
   },
   {"name": [{
       "grade": "A",
       "position": "JSE",
       "data": [
         {
           "commission": 271,
           "address": "street1"
         }]}
     ]
   }
```

#### Each thing enclosed in `{` and `}` is a single object

It is possible to have two separate variables, for the two elements, e.g.:

```
  a = {"name": [{
       "grade": "A",
       "position": "JSE",
       "data": [{
           "commission": 271,
           "address": "street1"
         } ]}]
   }

   b = {"name": [{
       "grade": "A",
       "position": "JSE",
       "data": [
         {
           "commission": 271,
           "address": "street1"
         }]}
     ]
   }
```

But almost certainly that is not what you wanted.

I think what you wanted was the following:

#### To remove the outer array and the "name" key

You might try the following:

```js
EmployeeData=[
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [{
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          } ]}]
    },
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [
          {
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          }]}
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  const arr = EmployeeData.map(thing=>thing.name)
  
  console.log(arr)
```

#### But even the above has one extra level of arrays that you probably do not want, so how about this:

```js
EmployeeData=[
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [{
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          } ]}]
    },
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [
          {
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          }]}
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  const arr = EmployeeData.map(thing=>thing.name[0])
  
  console.log(arr)
```

#### And even that doesn't make much sense, as you probably want to keep "name"

That would be best to do as a separate property, at the same level as "grade".

For example:

```js
EmployeeData=[
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [{
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          } ]}]
    },
    {"name": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [
          {
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          }]}
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  const arr = EmployeeData.map(thing=>thing.name)
  
  console.log(arr)
```

#### But even the above has one extra level of arrays that you probably do not want, so how about this:

```js
EmployeeData=[
    {"name": [{
        "name": "John",
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [{
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          } ]}]
    },
    {"name": [{
        "name": "Kelly",
        "grade": "A",
        "position": "JSE",
        "data": [
          {
            "commission": 271,
            "address": "street1"
          }]}
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  const arr = EmployeeData.map(thing=>thing.name[0])
  
  console.log(arr)
```